# BitLocker Full Disk Encryption - WIN

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, bitlocker

I am encountering a recurring issue with BitLocker Full Disc Encryption (WIN) via Policy Management on Windows devices. The issue manifests as a failed encryption attempt due to the presence of multiple numerical passwords.

1. The policy fails with the following error message:

```
"state": "FAILED",
    "detail": "Bitlocker Protected - More than one numerical password currently set. This configuration is not supported, please ensure that the system only has one or no numerical password in place."
```

2. To resolve this issue, I manually remove the second numerical password using the following command:

```
     manage-bde c: -protectors -delete -id {}
```

3. After restarting the end-user's laptop, the encryption policy successfully applies.

However, the second numerical password mysteriously reappears after an unknown period, causing the encryption policy to fail again. This issue is affecting a significant number of devices, and I have been unable to identify a consistent pattern or solution to prevent it from recurring.

How do I identify the process that is adding the numerical recovery protector, and the date and time that it was added?

Comment: With Policy Management you mean Group Policy? How are your devices enrolled and managed?